# Acceder a los elementos internos de un jFrame desde otra clase

Tags: java

Lo que quiero saber es como puedo acceder a elementos como jTextField o jLabel de un jFrame sin ponerlos **public static** desde dentro de las configuraciones de netbeans

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplemente provee a las propiedades getters y setters para acceder a ellas.

```
private JTextField txtNombre;

public JTextField getTxtNombre() { return txtNombre; }

public void setTxtNombre(JTextField txtNombre) {
    this.txtNombre = txtNombre;
}
```

Adicionalmente, te recomiendo dividir tu aplicación en capas. Puedes tener la lógica en una capa, en otra los formularios y en otra las clases que manejan los formularios (controladores), usando el patrón **MVC**.

Por ejemplo:

**Formulario**

```
public class FormRegistro extends JFrame {

    private JButton btnRegistrar;
    private FormRegistroController controller;

    public FormRegistro() {
        super("Registro de personal");
        controller = new FormRegistroController(this);
        initComponents();
    }

    private void initComponents() {
        ...
        btnRegistrar = new JButton("Registrar");
        btnRegistrar.addActionListener(controller);
    }
}
```

Este formulario será manejado por un controlador. Este se encargará de escuchar los eventos que ocurran en el formulario y actuará de acuerdo a ellos.

**Controlador**

```
public class FormRegistroController implements ActionListener {

    private FormRegistro ui;

    public FormRegistroController(FormRegistro ui) {
        this.ui = ui;
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
        String actionCommand = event.getActionCommand();
        if(actionCommand.equals("Registrar")) {
           // se ha clickeado el botón registrar
           String nombre = ui.getTextNombre().getText();
           // obtienes los demás valores y luego registras
        }
    }
}
```

Es bueno que desde el principio te preocupes por seguir buenos estándares y prácticas de programación, reforzarán mucho tu aprendizaje. Más adelante, cuando veas base de datos puedes usar el patrón *DAO* o *Repository* por ejemplo.

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta @Mitsu

Comment: De nada David. Bienvenido.

Answer (score 0):

No tengo tu codigo asi que lo que tengo es una idea de que estas haciendo, mi opinion es la siguiente.

Crea un metodo publico dentro de tu Jframe que devuelva los controles del Jframe dentro de estos controles del frame estan tus JtextField y todos los restantes controles. Si usas esta idea debes de tener en cuenta que has de marcar los controles que desees devolver de alguna manera pues puede ocurrir que sin querer tomes controles no deseados.